# Domain forwarding without running a server with CloudFlare

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

CloudFlare has a great option in PageRules to set up URL forwarding. I can set it to `*.example.com/*` to redirect everything to a different domain.

My problem is that while this works perfectly, this needs valid A / CNAME records in the DNS page. For example a server or an S3 bucket. I don't get why is this needed, since no requests will ever hit the server via this forwarding.

My question is: is there a way to set up URL forwarding via CloudFlare which doesn't require running a server?

Comment: What's wrong with the S3 bucket approach you mention? As it's pay for usage, you won't pay anything, and it requires no server management.

Comment: My only problem is that I need to set up 2 buckets even for totally empty forwarding domains. Not the end of the world, but a user cannot have more then 100 buckets, so you'd litter / fill out an account by simple having 50 redirected domains (www, and non-www).

Comment: You can request an increase in the bucket limit. Amazon is happy to do this if you have a good reason.